# Finding the time taken for a asp.net page to render

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, performance, rendering

I am having an asp.net page which i was showing as a pop up using Nyromodel.
the page contains

1. 4 div which is showing as Tabs (using Jquery Tabs).
2. 4 Repeater . 
   Each repeater I am having a custom control and I am setting the
   value    from db by setting the datasource to repeater. (This query
   may have    300-500 rows).
3. 1 infragistics UltraWebGrid. I add
   selected values    to the grid.

So the problem is it is taking too much time to render if I perform any operation in that UI.
I logged the sp execution time, then I found that SP i taking only 2-3 seconds. But the control will render completely after 30-40 seconds.
So sp execution time alone is not enough to satisfy the my lead. So kindly help me how to analysis the time of rendering the control. Thanks for any Input

Comment: Set `Trace = "true"` in your `Page Directive` now fisrt check which page event is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend you profile your web page using something like jetbrains's dotTrace or RedGate's profiler. They cost some $$ but highly worth it. You can probably download a trial in the mean time. I believe Visual Studio has some profiling built into it, but I've never been able to use as effectively as dotTrace.